# Creating a subclass that inherits from an ArcPy superclass?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, conda, subclass

I would like to create a subclass that inherits methods from the `arcpy` Describe class, as in:

```py
import arcpy

class my_sublass(arcpy.Describe):
    pass
```

However, `arcpy.Describe` is a function (that returns a class object, according to [ESRI](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe.htm)), not a class in and of itself. How can I code `my_subclass` such that it inherits from the Describe class?

For reference, I am in Python 3, using a cloned environment from Pro's default `conda` distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can.  If you dig into the arcpy source you'll find that `arcpy.Describe` essentially returns a wrapper around a non-python binary object (see line 369 in `<install dir>\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py`) which doesn't have a class you can inherit from.

However, you could fake a subclass, by creating a stand-alone class that:

- in `__init__`, accepts a value to describe then creates and stores the describe instance
- defines any custom properties or methods you want
- automatically passes through any attempts to access `Describe` object properties to the real describe instance and returns the result using a [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method.

A simple example:

```
import arcpy


class CustomDescribe(object):

    def __init__(self, thing):
        self._desc = arcpy.Describe(thing)
        self.test_value = 'Hello'

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """Pass any other attribute or method calls through to the underlying Describe object"""
        return getattr(self._desc, attr)

    def test_method(self):
        return 'World!'


a = CustomDescribe(r'C:\temp\Default.gdb')

print(a.datatype)
print(a.test_value)
print(a.test_method())
```

```
Workspace
Hello
World!
```

Comment: I'm just learning about coding with classes, and this seems wonderfully sneaky. I think I understand the logic of `__getattr__`: it's kind of synthesizing the class tree lookup without directly inheriting attributes of `Describe`, right? Is that what you mean by "faking" it? Also, why the leading underscore for `self._desc`?

Comment: Yes, any call to a property or method that isn't explicitly defined by your class will get passed automatically to [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) (if you define a `__getattr__` method). It's not a subclass of Describe, it's just pretending to be, so it's "faking it".  The underscore prefix is a hint to programmers/IDEs/code analysers etc.. that a variable or method is intended for internal use, i.e it's private. This convention is defined in PEP 8, though python doesn't enforce it.

Comment: Ah, now that I'm looking through `arcpy` source, I see tons of those leading underscores. Why would ESRI code their software like this? Is there an inherent advantage to structuring fake inheritance in this way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Whether a variable is supposed to be private/internal has nothing to do with what I called faking a subclass. The issue with `Describe` and other objects that arcpy wraps is that they have no class to inherit from, they're just an interface to non-python objects, kind of like what SWIG does https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG

Comment: Oh, because an ArcObject isn't a Python class! Ok, I get it. Thank you for your help, this has been educational in the extreme.